# 401 Unauthorized when running mvn compile

Tags: maven

I'm running `mvn compile -e -X` in a JMeter project directory from cmd prompt and I'm getting a 401 unauthorized:
[image]

What I'd imagine the HTTP request to be, works fine in Powershell and gives me a 200 response.
So the token I'm using does work.

```
$MyPat = 'passwordHere'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri 'https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/maven/maven/v1/microsoft/aspnet/signalr/signalr-client-sdk/1.0/signalr-client-sdk-1.0.pom' -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $B64Pat"}
```

I tried running Wireshark to view the HTTP request but nothing comes up for some reason.

Here is the settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>maven@Release</id>      
      <username>mycompanyproject</username>
      <password>passwordHere</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>mycompany</id>
      <username>mycompanyproject</username>
      <password>passwordHere</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Here's is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>au.com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany-jmeter-plugins</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompany</id>
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompanyproject-visualstudio-com-mycompanyproject-maven</id>
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/maven/maven/v1</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>mycompany</id>
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/mycompany/maven/v1</url>         
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>       
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>mycompanyproject-visualstudio-com-mycompanyproject-maven</id>
            <url>https://mycompanyproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/maven/maven/v1</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <modules>
        <module>signalr</module>
        <module>hoconreader</module>
        <module>propertyfilereader</module>
        <module>jsonbackendlistener</module>
        <module>samplerjavaexample</module>
        <module>tokengenerator</module>
        <module>data-tenantdownload</module>
        <module>data-invoicegenius</module>
        <module>data-unittests</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>ratio-data-generator</module>
        <module>timinglistener</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have paid closer attention to the suggestions at:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

It was because the  for my  in settings.xml didn't match what I had in pom.xml.

Making them the same fixed my issue.